# Some confusing basic inequalities on the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal Function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am a beginner in harmonic analysis and I already know the definition of Hardy Littlewood Maximum Function. Our next considerations are all focused on $f\in L^1\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $, but we do not guarantee $f\in C\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $. Recall the Hardy Littlewood Maximum Function is $Mf\left( x \right) =\mathop {\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{r>0}\frac{1}{\left| B\left( x,r \right) \right|}\int_{B\left( x,r \right)}{\left| f\left( y \right) \right|\mathrm{d}y}$.

Now, I have some confusion:

1. If $f\in L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $, which inequality is correct (or both): $\left\| Mf \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}\geqslant \left\| f \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$ or $\left\| Mf \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}\leqslant \left\| f \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$? Then if $f\in L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $ cannot be guaranteed, which inequality is correct?
2. Can $Mf\geqslant \left| f \right|$ a.e. be obtained without $f\in C\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $?

My question basically comes from this reference: "LECTURE NOTES ON HARMONIC ANALYSIS" by Chengchun Hao. Specifically, we can refer to Theorem 3.2.2. and Proposition 3.2.3. I know they may be trivial, but I cannot fully understand these inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

1. These two quantities are equal always.
2. Yes, this is true for all measurable $f$.

Let's handle 2) first.

For $f$ measurable, if $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$, this follows since almost every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ is a Lebesgue point of $|f|$, i.e.
$$|f(x)| =\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|dy}{|B(x,r)|}\leq Mf(x)\text{,}$$
and if $f\notin L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$, then $Mf(x)=\infty$ everywhere.

Now as for 1), from 2) we immediately have
$$\left\| Mf \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}\geqslant \left\| f \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}\text{.} $$
However, since $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}$ a.e., then certainly its average on every ball is at most  $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}$, regardless of the ball, so we have $$\left\| Mf \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}\leqslant \left\| f \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$$
as well.

Comment: I do not quite understand your last argument. If you start from $f\leq Mf$ (or what is $M$?), then we get by taking averages (and potentially suprema over all balls) $$ \Vert Mf \Vert_\infty \leq \Vert M (Mf) \Vert_\infty. $$ It is already late, so probably I am just being tired. What am I missing?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven using "M" was definitely confusing there, I changed it to $K$, perhaps that's clearer?

Comment: Very much so. Thanks! Is there a reason you are using $K$ instead of $\Vert f \Vert_\infty$?

Comment: I guess not really, I just wanted to adress OP's concern that a priori, we aren't in $L^\infty$, but I don't think that really matters and in retrospect it just confused things, as $||f||_{L^\infty}$ is still a well defined extended real anyway.  I will edit it.

Comment: It seems very reasonable. Perhaps in my settings, local integrability is not necessary because I make $f$ satisfy global $L^1$ integrability. Additionally, when $f$ does not have local integrability, what I really want to know is whether $\left\| Mf \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$ must have an infinite order not lower than $\left\| f \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$. Is that really true?

Comment: @SizheDing I'm a little unsure what you mean by "infinite order"?  In general even if you are working with extended reals, you just have one $\infty$, it's not like cardinality where there are more than one infinity.  Unless you are doing some kind of nonstandard analysis, in which case I couldn't really comment intelligently on that.

Comment: @M W I'm sorry for using abbreviated terms. Actually, I consider the function series $\left\{ f_m \right\} \subset L^1\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $ and assume $\left\| f_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}<\infty $ not always holds. Generally, we say that $\left\{ f_m \right\} $ diverges in the sense of $L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right) $. What I want to know is, is $\left\| Mf_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$ approaching infinity faster than $\left\| f_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$?

Comment: @SizheDing Firstly, if $\left\| f_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}<\infty$ does not always hold, that is very different from simply saying $\{f_m\}$ diverges in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.  Secondly, $\left\| Mf_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}=\left\| f_m \right\| _{L^{\infty}\left( \mathbb{R} ^n \right)}$ for all values of $m$, so if they were approaching infinity, they would both be approaching equally fast or slow - they are the same quantities.

Comment: @M W Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @SizheDing no problem, glad I could help!